# Averaging bang for the buck

Tags: data-visualization, mean, aggregation, rating

I'm building a table/graph to compare multiple video cards according to a given benchmark.

The benchmark consists of multiple measurements using games. For each benchmark measurement, I build a performance per cost metric. I want to average all the performance per cost metrics for given a benchmark.

For instance, consider this:

Video Card: GeForce GTX 1070

Data for the arithmetic average of the:

- Average FPS for 15 games at 1080p, medium quality = 100
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 1080p, medium quality = 90
- Average FPS for 15 games at 1080p, high quality = 80
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 1080p, high quality = 75
- Average FPS for 15 games at 1440p, high quality = 65
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 1440p, high quality = 60
- Average FPS for 15 games at 2160p, high quality = 50
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 2160p, high quality = 40

Note: FPS = Frames per second

Suppose price = $350

Now I can calculate a bang for the buck for each benchmark measurement:

- Average FPS for 15 games at 1080p, medium quality = 100/350
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 1080p, medium quality = 90/350
- Average FPS for 15 games at 1080p, high quality = 80/350
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 1080p, high quality = 75/350
- Average FPS for 15 games at 1440p, high quality = 65/350
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 1440p, high quality = 60/350
- Average FPS for 15 games at 2160p, high quality = 50/350
- Minimum FPS for 15 games at 2160p, high quality = 40/350

While the multiple numbers may be useful in some circumstances, I need a more compact representation using a single number to represent the bang for the buck for all measurements of this benchmark.

So I need some function like:

SomeAverage(100/350, 90/350, 80/350, 75/350, 65/350, 60/350, 50/350, 40/350) = ??? FPS/$

This single number will be used to compare different video cards, creating a ranking. It may also be normalized into a cost-benefit rating (like from 0 to 5 stars).

What type of average/mean (e.g arithmetic, geometric, harmonic, median, etc) should use to create this rating? And, most importantly, why?

Comment: Thought I should add this video for future reference, from the GATech's Computer Architecture course: https://youtu.be/3_drIF-lENE

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you aggregate measurements you will lose some information.

In this case, you lose the specificity of the particular resolutions.

In regards to the choice of aggregate function, mean would suit you well here. It will provide a representation across all resolutions which is what you want. Median would be a good choice if you had some outliers that that would adversely affect the mean results (e.g. a card doing 1000 FPS at 1080p and 40 at 2160p).

At the base level, FPS measurements are highly correlated, i.e. if card A does better than card B at 1080p it will most likely do well at 2160p as well. So the additional measurements do not add much additional information.

If you find a metric that that is less correlated (maybe frame timings) you will be able to provide better information.